# a question about statistics in R that I can't summarize briefly

Tags: r

my data looks kind of like this (with maps 2,3,6,7... in between):

| animal | map | velocity | frequency | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1,235 | 115 | RA |
| 1 | 1 | 0,436 | 115 | RA |
| 1 | 1 | 3,124 | 115 | RA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 4 | 1,212 | 116 | RA |
| 1 | 4 | 0,123 | 116 | RA |
| 1 | 4 | 1,124 | 116 | RA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 5 | 1,212 | 122 | LV |
| 1 | 5 | 0,132 | 122 | LV |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 9 | 2,234 | 134 | LV |
| 1 | 9 | 0,123 | 134 | LV |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 10 | 1,155 | 120 | RA |
| 2 | 10 | 1,122 | 120 | RA |
| 2 | 10 | 1,124 | 120 | RA |
| 2 | 10 | 4,233 | 120 | RA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 12 | 1,124 | 134 | RA |
| 2 | 12 | 0,241 | 134 | RA |
| 2 | 12 | 2,234 | 134 | RA |
| 2 | 12 | 3,234 | 134 | RA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 14 | 0,234 | 120 | LV |
| 2 | 14 | 2,324 | 120 | LV |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 16 | 1,424 | 86 | LV |
| 2 | 16 | 0,012 | 86 | LV |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

In total there are 4 different animals.

I want to test whether a change of frequency changes the velocity.

In my data, 2 of the maps always belong together (i.e., 1 and 4 describe the same animal, but in another recording; 5 and 9, 10 and 12). This means that, for example, in this data, the 1st and 4th row belong together.

How can I test the influence of a change of frequency, separated by the location?

Map 1 and 4 could be compared using a paired t-test. But how do I include the frequency?
How could I automatically consider the location?

My idea was to calculate the differences between each row-pair and then calculate the mean of the differences for each map-pair.
And then, I would have to compare these values considering the change of frequency.

[image]

Suppose I would want to calculate these differences. How would i perform this task with R?
I think i would have to rearrange my table to this format:

| animal | velocity1 | velocity2 | frequency difference | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,235 | 1,212 | 1 | RA |
| 1 | 0,436 | 0,123 | 1 | RA |
| 1 | 3,124 | 1,124 | 1 | RA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 1,212 | 2,234 | 12 | LV |
| 1 | 0,132 | 0,123 | 12 | LV |

Comment: In these data you cannot isolate the effect of frequency, because changes in frequency are *always* associated with a change  in animal or a change in map.

Comment: True
but isn't there any test like for example mixed model where I can consider all the factors?

Comment: No test can create information where there is none.

Comment: Well the thing is map is just an index. 
Map 1 is the first recording with the conditions 1 frequency and 1 location.
all these 3 information belong together

Comment: To me, it is not very clear what was done to answer what question. "information belong together" could mean anything from a vague similarity to a repeated measurement of the same thing under the same conditions with just different names. Next to a better explanation, a minimal, complete, verifiable example would be helpful to the part of the question that concerns performing the Analysis in R.

Comment: *"In my data, 2 of the maps always belong together (i.e., 1 and 4 describe the same animal"* What does that 'describe the same animal' mean? With this data you only have 4 animals so a lot of rows describe the same animal. Why do maps 1 and 4 'belong together'?

Comment: It would help if you describe the experiment that created the data (the meaning of 'maps', 'velocity' etc is very abstract and unclear). You can't just have some table with data and start asking about how to perform the statistical analysis relating to some research questions. You also need to describe the actual research that has been done to obtain the data based on which a statistical model can be created. A data table on it's own, without the context, is meaningless.